# When spring boot uses JPA, multi table inheritance leads to inconsistent result set types?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

About the use of JPA in springboot, there are three tables A, B and C. table A inherits table B, and table B inherits table C. when querying the data with the findAll() function of JpaRepository query statement of table B, it is found that the data found in table B will be automatically converted to the type of table A, and the field clazz_ that cannot be found will appear when querying the data with SQL Question of table B.(The simple generalization is that the result set queried by the jparepository of the parent table is automatically mapped to the smallest subclass type)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no question here, but I think you misunderstand JPA inheritance. When query for Instances of entity B, JPA MUST return all instances that can be matched with Bs - this includes all its subclasses, such as A. A Manager is a type of employee, so if you query on employees, you would expect to get back managers too. As for clazz_ not being found - multi table inheritance means that a B (or A) entity have data in the B table as well as in the C (parent) table. The row in the C table should have the discriminator field that tells JPA what type of data it is (pure C, B or A data).

Comment: OK,Thank you very much.Your answer is of great reference significance.